# How to install Ubuntu on Intel NUC10i7FNH

Tags: boot, system-installation, 19.10, intel-nuc

I recently purchased an Intel NUC10i7FNH-based system and wanted to boot from a LiveUSB drive loaded with Ubuntu Linux 19.10 LTS. However, after a few seconds the screen goes blank and the machine shuts itself down.

Before shutting down, the following message is displayed on the screen:

> Error communicating to TPM chip

[image: Error communicating to TPM chip]

System Configuration:

- Intel NUC10i7FNH
- Samsung EVO Plus 970 1TB
- 2 x 16GB Corsair SODIMM 2666MHz

Has anybody been able to install Ubuntu on the new generation NUCs?

Comment: Did you try suggestion in bug 1850668 :

Did you check if TPM chip was enabled on BIOS option?

Refer:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178285/how-to-solve-ima-error-communicating-to-tpm-chip-messages-during-boot/1178287

Comment: According to specs said model has no TPM chip. Refer: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/188811/intel-nuc-10-performance-kit-nuc10i7fnh.html

Comment: Have you checked for any BIOS/firmware updates from the vendor?

Comment: I did. I applied latest firmware v37 after purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Have you check out this [supported OS for your NUC](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005628/intel-nuc.html)? Seems like they're only supporting Windows 10 at the moment.

Unrelated, but we also recently purchased a handful units of the same model, NUC10i7FNH, to run our CI/CD pipelines, and our custom Yocto OS isn't booting on these guys either.

Comment: yeah at the moment only Windog is supported.. it may be a few months before Linux support arrives..

Answer (score 1):

Installed Wednesday - Ubuntu 19.10.

```
NUC10i7FNH1, Crucial 32G (2x16G) 2666 RAM, WD Black 1TB NVME, Samsung 2T EVO 860 2.5"
```

Hangs if you enable updates during install (while fetching grub2 update).
Without updates, installs fine (from usb stick), then after updating via
wifi, the ethernet works also (with 5.3.29 kernel).  Wifi seems supports
802.11ac only, but not WIFI6.

This seems like it might be a problem, but it works fine:

```
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    0.396873] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10710U CPU @ 1.10GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0xa6, stepping: 0x0)
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    0.396968] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    0.396971] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 10: 8c20000000041136
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    0.396972] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR 2a5e1080 MISC 3040038086
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    0.396975] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:a0660 TIME 1581544124 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode c6
```

The TPM error remains (no TPM or vPro):

```
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    2.439905] ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    2.452046] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    2.452770] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    2.453494] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    2.453989] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    2.454510] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    2.454928] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    2.455345] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
Feb 12 13:48:52 u32 kernel: [    2.455763] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip
```

Comment: Seems to need a newer kernel. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208978/intel-corporation-device-80860d4f-is-not-supported-on-ubuntu-18-04-3
NUC10i7FNH
this Network adapter Intel Corporation Device [8086:0d4f] is new and supported by mainline Linux kernel since the 5.5 Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I just brought up Kubuntu on an Intel NUC10i7FNH, running 32 GB Corsair Vengeance memory and a WD BLUE SN550 1TB SSD.

Per recommendations above, I declined getting updates during installation. I have been presented with a functional machine in as little as 15 minutes (I didn't time the installation, but it completed while I was watching the screen, so it was quite a rapid installation). I am writing this from the system. I have yet to go through the WiFi system- I am using the built-in Ethernet port. I also have not tried the audio features, but I will check as to whether the audio works through the HDMI port, and go from there. Thank you, Ubuntu community, for making this little computer work out of the box. Oh, and yes, I did update the firmware prior to attempting the installation.

Best Regards,
Shane

Comment: Just checked and WiFi and Bluetooth features are fully functional!