# Intel Corporation Device [8086:0d4f] is not supported on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: networking, drivers, server

I am currently unable to install ubuntu server 18.04.03 LTS on the latest intel NUC10i7FNH.

Ubuntu always states both network adapters as unclaimed. The previous version (NUC8i7BEH) has the same network controller I219-V and worked like a charm.

```
*-network:0 UNCLAIMED
     description:  Network controller
     product: Intel Corporation
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 14.3
     ...
```

Without network it is not even possible to follow most suggestions how to get it enabled, because it is impossible to fetch new packages from internet.

Here are some more information as requested:

The output from: modprobe -v e1000e && dmesg | grep e10

```
[ 3447.889394] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[ 3447.889395] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
```

The output from: sudo lspci -knn

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0d4f]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2081]
01:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] [8086:15e7] (rev 06)
```

For me this looks somehow, as the kernal driver would not be in use :-/

Here are a few more information i got from playiung around with 19.10 desktop version.

```
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.3.0-29-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-024) (gcc version 9.2.1 20191008 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2)) #31-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 17:27:26 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.3.0-29.31-generic 5.3.13)
```

output from lshw:

```
  *-network:0
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: Intel Corporation
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 14.3
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:14.3
       Logischer Name: wlp0s20f3
       Version: 00
       Seriennummer: c8:09:a8:9c:cd:e0
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-29-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 ip=192.168.178.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6023114000-6023117fff
```

The output from: modprobe -v e1000e && dmesg | grep e10

```
[    2.357430] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    2.357430] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    2.357616] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    2.562796] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    2.634139] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 1c:69:7a:60:44:f0
[    2.634140] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    2.634258] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 13, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    2.634991] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: renamed from eth0
[    5.103285] checking generic (4000000000 e10000) vs hw (4000000000 10000000)
[   15.806697] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
```

output from lspci:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V [8086:0d4f]
    DeviceName:  LAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V [8086:2081]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: The information has been added

Comment: You'll get the 5.3 kernel if you do a normal update of 18.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Network adapter `Intel Corporation Device [8086:0d4f]` is new and supported by mainline Linux kernel since the 5.5 Linux kernel.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers?h=v5.5&id=914ee9c436cbe90c8ca8a46ec8433cb614a2ada5

Ubuntu maintainers backported this fix to Ubuntu 5.3 kernels that are shipped with the 19.10 Ubuntu release and will be shipped with 18.04.4 LTS shortly.

At the moment the current HWE 18.04 kernel is the 5.3.

If you connect your server to the internet by other means and do

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

all should work.

If the network traffic is an issue, you can update only kernel by

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

You can manually download the package with its dependencies https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/linux-generic-hwe-18.04

You'll need only linux-XXX packages. Other dependencies should be already there.

Then install them using `dpkg`.

Comment: This is interesting news to me. In the meanwhile I was playing arround with ubuntu 19.10 desktop version. This was capable of running the network adapter out of the box.

But it is just on kerne 5.3 I think. 

But I will check if there is an working way for me, to get a 5.5 kernal into 18.04.03 server version.

Thanks for the tip so far

Comment: 18.04 should have the 5.3 kernel if you update the system. I looked into Ubuntu kernel code and Ubuntu kernels have this fix backported. I will update the answer.

Comment: The issue is, that io have no network at all on this machine. So i can not run the updates on the normal way. Is there a way to do such an upgrade based on a usb stick?

Comment: Sure you can do it from a USB.  You'll need to download some packages. Maybe it will be easier if you use your phone as a USB modem.

Comment: Or wait a few days. the 18.04.4 should appear in a few days.

Comment: The new kernel works like a charm ... at least from the network point of view. I am now from 4.15 to 5.30 and the ethernet is working. I was booting the ssd in a different machine to do the update. Thank You very much for finding this solution.