# ima: error communicating to tpm chip but no TPM settings

Tags: boot, tpm

Apologies as I think this may be a duplicate of [How to solve "ima: error communicating to tpm chip" messages during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178285/how-to-solve-ima-error-communicating-to-tpm-chip-messages-during-boot)
But I am hoping you can help.

I installed the current version of Lubuntu (which I have used for many years) over the weekend on my new HP Z230 workstation.

All was going fine till Google remote desktop kept me from accessing secondary drives. Removing it fixed this problem, but the next restart led to the above error during boot.

Having tried a number of times, I can boot Lubuntu in recovery mode, I can boot into a live USB, though this produces the above error before starting. Normal start up is rare, and instead the system stops at the HP screen.

The BIOS itself does not appear to have a ton of settings, so I cannot just enable it as far as I can tell.

Does anyone have any ideas what has happened & how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this site on my phone, but with a little more investigation, the live usb only seems to boot in the safe graphics mode, while a random windows 8 hd I found booted up with no problem (giving me more confidence that it isn't hardware)

Answer (score 0):

So, what seems to have worked for me....

Because of the fact it worked in safe graphics mode, I unplugged the graphics card. I then unplugged the machine completely and left it overnight (I had done this before, but not overnight). I later plugged it all in again (including graphics card) the next day & found that the system would boot again.

Whether these things are related I don't know, but if you can try it, I guess.