# Xubuntu 22.04.1 no longer boots

Tags: boot, xubuntu, 22.04

I installed Xubuntu 22.04.1 (alongside Win10Pro) on an HP Z620 workstation about a month ago, rebooting several times during the installation and configuration process. It's been running mostly great since then until today when I manually rebooted in an attempt to see if that would clear up some problems with Zoom. After selecting "Ubuntu" in the GRUB menu, I see the following entries on the screen:

```
[  1.(long decimal)] ima: Error Communicating to TPM Chip
[  1.(long decimal)] ima: Error Communicating to TPM Chip
[  1.(long decimal)] ima: Error Communicating to TPM Chip
[  1.(long decimal)] ima: Error Communicating to TPM Chip
[  1.(long decimal)] ima: Error Communicating to TPM Chip
[  1.(long decimal)] ima: Error Communicating to TPM Chip
[  1.(long decimal)] ima: Error Communicating to TPM Chip
[  1.(long decimal)] ima: Error Communicating to TPM Chip

/dev/sdb5: clean, 194642/4571136 files, 3954344/18271488 blocks
[  7.973521] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

EDIT: The following 5 lines no longer print after disconnecting my USB webcam and USB Bluetooth dongle for my headset, but the machine still fails to boot.

```
[  8.731849] usb 3-1: 1:1: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x3
[  8.749735] Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 6 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
[  8.749735] Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 9 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
[  8.749735] Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 4 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
[  8.749735] Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 11 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
[  9.096576]
```

and then it appears to hang indefinitely with what looks like a graphical underscore/cursor in the upper left corner of the screen. If I press the power button, the Xubuntu logo comes up briefly and the machine powers off.

I've always had the warnings about the (non-existent) TPM chip. I tried running boot-repair and that did not help. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Following @HolyBlackCat 's advice, I switched to a terminal and ran `journalctl -b` and found the following errors:

```
ima: Error Communicating to TPM Chip (I've had this before w/o issue)
event7: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0xc022d, and key code 103: Invalid argument
pipewire[1156]: spa.v412: '/dev/video1' VIDIOC_QUERYCTL: Input/output error
VMware-init[1361]: /usr/sbin/vmware-authdlauncher: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
pulseaudio[1486]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "ima: error communicating to tpm chip" messages during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178285/how-to-solve-ima-error-communicating-to-tpm-chip-messages-during-boot)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, thanks for the suggestions, but I've always had those TPM chip warnings, so they are not the cause of the boot failure.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F1(..6) to switch to a different console, login in text mode, then look in `journalctl -b` for any errors?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thank you. I've updated the post with the errors I saw in the journal.

Comment: Can you paste the entire log somewhere? Not sure if I'll see anything in it, but maybe someone else will.