# Bios bug and TPM error problem

Tags: boot, bios, tpm, helpfile

When i try to open my pc . It shows as following
0.962535] ina: Error Communicating to TPM chip

0.986438] ina: Error Communicating to TPM chip

1.010434] ina: Error Communicating to TPM chip

1.030507] ina: Error Communicating to TPM chip

1.050507] ina: Error Communicating to TPM chip

1.070506] ina: Error Communicating to TPM chip 1.0905211 ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

1.110518] ina: Error Communicating to TPM chip

I

1.8888811 ACPI Error: Aborting method SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTO._SDD due to previ

1.8132041 ACPI Error: Aborting nethod SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTO._GTF due to previ

1.806670] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [SB.PCIO.SATO.P [ 1.8110511 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol _SB.PC1O.SATO.P [ 1.816891) ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [SB.PCIO.SATO.P [ [ [ /dev/sdaб: clean, 190521/654080 files, 2526562/2613760 blocks

[

1.819108) ACPI Error: Aborting method SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTO._SDD due to previ

1.821240] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol _SB.PCIO.SATO.P 1.823438] ACPI Error: Aborting method SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTO. GTF due to previ

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What is the question?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178285/how-to-solve-ima-error-communicating-to-tpm-chip-messages-during-boot

Comment: @Pilot6 yes i am using ubuntu