# How to anti-solve the "ima: error communicating to tpm chip" error?

Tags: boot, lubuntu, tpm

I've read:

[How to solve "ima: error communicating to tpm chip" messages during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178285/how-to-solve-ima-error-communicating-to-tpm-chip-messages-during-boot)

and basically, people suggest I make sure my machine's TPM support is enabled.

Well, I certainly don't want to do that! I don't condone its existence and I want the kernel *not* to try to communicate with it. How can I tell it not to?

Note: I'm using Lubuntu 22.04 LTS, in case this matters. The kernel version is 5.19.0-43-generic.