# Ima error communicating tpm, /dev/sda2 issue

Tags: ssd, tpm

There is an error showing while starting system,hp - ubuntu

```
[0.099473] DMARL [firmware bug]: no firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0*00000000bd000000-0*00000000bf1fffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
[2.371211] ima: Error communicating to TPM chip
[2.374373] ima: Error communicating to TPM chip
[2.377706] ima: Error communicating to TPM chip
[2.381040] ima: Error communicating to TPM chip
[2.384923] ima: Error communicating to TPM chip
[2.388474] ima: Error communicating to TPM chip
[2.391800] ima: Error communicating to TPM chip
[2.395331] ima: Error communicating to TPM chip
/dev/sda2: clean, 267254/14622720 files, 9669470/58476288 blocks
```

How can I resolve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "ima: error communicating to tpm chip" messages during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178285/how-to-solve-ima-error-communicating-to-tpm-chip-messages-during-boot)

Comment: FYI the "/dev/sda2" message is NOT an "issue" message, the issue you have is the TPM chip communication issue, so see guiverc's link.

Comment: In a terminal run:

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
Navigate with the arrow keys on your keyboard to the place where it says:

quiet splash
and change it to:

quiet loglevel=0 splash
Save the file and run:

sudo update-grub 
Reboot and you will see that there are no messages anymore of the TPM error.   This stopped showing the error message. Can anybody explain the working of above command ?

Comment: /dev/sda2: clean, 267254/14622720 files, 9669470/58476288 blocks...now iam get only this one. Can someone help me explain and resolve this?